# Moodle 1.9.4 no public key

Tags: networking, openssl, moodle, mahara

I can't get a public key for my Moodle network, the xlrpc is installed on Ubuntu. Can anyone help?

Moodle: 1.9.4

Apache: 2.2.8

PHP: 5.2.4-2

Error on debug mode:

```
Warning: openssl_csr_new() [function.openssl-csr-new]: dn: add_entry_by_NID 17 ->
Moodle (failed) in /var/www/moodle_teste/mnet/lib.php on line 361

Warning: openssl_csr_sign() [function.openssl-csr-sign]: cannot get CSR from 
parameter 1 in /var/www/moodle_teste/mnet/lib.php on line 362

Warning: openssl_x509_export() [function.openssl-x509-export]: cannot get cert 
from parameter 1 in /var/www/moodle_teste/mnet/lib.php on line 380

Warning: openssl_x509_free() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given 
in /var/www/moodle_teste/mnet/lib.php on line 381
```

Comment: Maybe try to update to a newer version or create an issue on [Moodle Tracker](https://tracker.moodle.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa).

Comment: It is a system in use, I can't update this. I will create an issue on Moodle Tracker, thanks.